# Rails3, MongoDB and Full calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, date, fullcalendar

I'm saving a record like this:

```
@availability.availability_date     = Time.zone.parse((params[:date][:day] + "/" + params[:date][:month] + "/" + params[:date][:year] + " "+ params[:date][:hour]).to_str).utc

@availability.end_availability_date = Time.zone.parse((params[:date][:day] + "/" + params[:date][:month] + "/" + params[:date][:year] + " "+ (params[:date][:hour].to_i + 1).to_s).to_str).utc
```

On my Mongo Document I have a record like this:

```
"availability_date" : ISODate("2014-10-09T05:00:00.000Z"),
"end_availability_date" : ISODate("2014-10-09T06:00:00.000Z"),
```

But on my view I select 2014-10-09 12:00 as start date and 2014-10-09 13:00 as end date. And that's fine, but when I try to show this information on my [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) I always get 2014-10-09 12:00 as start date and 2014-10-09 13:00 as end date, even though I set my fullcalendar with the option:

```
timezone: 'local',
```

What I'm doing wrong. Help me to understand and solve this issues with time zone, please.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: you probably need to check all the timezones involved. when they get handed of between layers and if the come back in the same zone you expect them to. write it down on a sheet of paper to keep track

Comment: How do you give these dates to fullcalendar? If you don't include the time zone there I think it might assume the time zone is whatever your default is

Comment: @RichardHermanson I added the dates, like this: start: "#{availability.availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")}",
      end:   "#{availability.end_availability_date.to_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%Z")}",

Comment: Which resolves to? Isn't there some isoformat function?

Comment: 2014-10-09 12:00 as start date and 2014-10-09 13:00 as end date, no matter what time zone a set on fullcalendar

Comment: Looks like it resolves to more than that. Looks you have time zone there